# Right view image not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I seem to not be able to get my image to appear next to my UITextField. I wanted to ask for some ideas as to why this might not show up?

Here is my code:

```
var errorImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: ("redx")))        
view?.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
view?.rightView = errorImageView
```

When I replace 'right' with 'left' (meaning use the left side) the image appears just fine on the left of the textbox, but for some reason right isn't working. Is there something wrong with frames or I need to change insets? Confused why it would work for left but not right.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was adding a new UITextField and restarting - i'm sure something strange just got caught up and made it appear like it wasn't working. It didn't have anything to do with frames, or anything of that sort.

I actually just created a new project, too, as a test, and this code above worked perfectly so just a random gremlin in my code, perhaps. All is well now, sorry to bother everyone :)